# how to Increment int value of column in multiple rows of a returned set by one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to be able to increment the int value of a column returned in a result set of multiple rows by 1. for instance the following query will return a result set from a table that looks like the following:

```
select numinbatch from items i where i.ID > @itemID and i.BatchID = @batchID

4
5
6
7
```

I want to update these values by incrementing them by 1 so that:

```
5
6
7
8
```

I have the following for now but Im getting a red squiggly error line under the plus sign.

```
declare @idToIncrement as int
declare cur cursor fast_forward for select numinbatch from items i where i.ID > @itemID and i.BatchID = @batchID

    open cur
    fetch next from cur into @idToIncrement

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
    EXEC

    --increment numinbatch or @idToIncrement
    @idToIncrement= @idToIncrement + 1

     fetch next from cur into @field1, @field2
    END

    close cur
    deallocate cur
```

I know that cursors are bad for performance so if any one has a better solution feel free to share.

Comment: I see your code, but I see no "plus sign" _(Im getting a red squiggly error line under the **plus sign**.)_

Comment: i took it out so it would be easier to read "@idToIncrement + 1 or @idToIncrement= @idToIncrement + 1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
select numinbatch + 1 numinbatch_increased_by_1
  from items i
 where i.ID > @itemID and i.BatchID = @batchID
```

If you want to `UPDATE` the values into the table, then

```
UPDATE items i
   SET numinbatch = numinbatch + 1
 WHERE i.ID > @itemID AND i.BatchID = @batchID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT numinbatch + 1 FROM items WHERE ID > @itemID AND BatchID = @batchID
```

assuming numinbatch is numeric. There's no need for a cursor.